# Flickering Page

Tags: javascript

when i am refreshing the page Flickering happens. I can see the resizing effect in page.How can i avoid this? I am using master page in my Project. In body tag i am using this(`<body onload="return SetContentHeight();" onresize="return SetContentHeight();">`) to call the function. My content page inside a table. So i am setting up height and width for this table. `SetContentHeight(){//Assigning Height and width of content page}`

Comment: Provide some code and some more details as to why you're resizing with javascript?  Can you use percentage widths instead?

Comment: btable4.height = Number(btable2.height) - (Number(btable3.height) + Number(btable5.height));
Width is not at a problm.But height is the problem.Other browser(except ie) its height is proper.Here btable2 is the main table.btable3 is header,btable5 footer.Then i am setting height for btable4,inside this content page will come.

Answer (score 0):

If you initiate your code after page load, you prevent. 
In page loading triggers resize, since page is rendered times before pageloaded.

so I suggest

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
   SetContentHeight();
 });
```

Comment: Inside body onload event  i am calling this function.                                                              <body onload="return SetContentHeight();" onresize="return SetContentHeight();">

Comment: After render onresize called, then, onload initiated. The code I provide, sets itself after page load.